# xPath expression for attributes that don't have ancestors with same attribute

Tags: ruby, xpath

I'm trying to extract elements with an attribute, and not extract the descendants separately that have the same attribute.

Using the following html:

```
<html><body>
  <div box>
    some text
    <div box>
      some more text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div box>
    this needs to be included as well
  </div>
</body></html>
```

I want to be able to extract the two outer `<div box>` and its descendants including the inner `<div box>`, but don't want to have the inner `<div box>` extracted separately.

I have tried using all sorts of different expressions but think I am missing something quite fundamental.  The main expression I have been trying is: `//[@box and not(ancestor::@box)` but this still returns two elements.

I am trying to do this using the 'Hpricot' (0.8.3) Gem in Ruby 1.9.2 as follows:

```
# Assuming html is set to the html above
doc = Hpricot(html)
elements = doc.search('//[@box and not(ancestor::@box)]')

# The following is returning 3 instead of 2
elements.size
```

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPATH is invalid.  You have to address something in order to use the predicate filter(e.g. []).  Otherwise, there isn't anything to filter.

**This XPATH works:**

```
//div[@box and not(ancestor::div/@box)]
```

If the elements aren't all guarenteed to be `<div>`, you can use a more generic match for elements:

```
//*[@box and not(ancestor::*/@box)]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed.  However, interestingly this didn't work with Hpricot.  I have moved over to Nokogiri and now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using `elements = doc.search('//[@box and not(ancestor::@box)]')` isn't correct.

Use `elements = doc.at('//div[@box]')` which will find the first occurrence.

I'd recommend using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) over Hpricot. Nokogiri is well supported, very flexible and more robust.

---

EDIT: Added because original question changed:

> Thanks that worked perfectly, except I forget to mention that I want to return multiple outer  elements. Sorry about that, I have updated the question. I will look into Nokogiri further, I didn't choose it originally because Hpricot seemed more approachable.

Remember that XPath acts like accessing a file in a directory at its simplest form, so you can drill down and search in "subdirectories". If you only want the outer `<div>` tags, then look inside the `<body>` level and no further:

```
doc.search('/html/body/div')
```

or, if you might have unadorned `div` tags along with the targets:

```
doc.search('/html/body/div[@box]')
```

Regarding Hpricot seeming more approachable:

Nokogiri implements a superset of Hpricot's accessors, allowing you to drop it into place for most uses. It supports XPath and CSS accessors allowing more intuitive ways of getting at data if you live in CSS and HTML and don't grok XPath. In addition there are many methods to find your desired target:

```
doc.search('body > div[box]')
(doc / 'body > div[box]')
doc.css('body > div[box]')
```

Nokogiri supports the `at` and `%` synonym found in Hpricot also, along with `css_at`, if you only want the first occurrence of something.

I started using Nokogiri after running into some situations where Hpricot exploded because it couldn't handle malformed news-feeds in the wilds.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly, except I forget to mention that I want to return multiple outer <div box> elements. Sorry about that, I have updated the question.  I will look into Nokogiri further, I didn't choose it originally because Hpricot seemed more approachable.

Comment: @Lawrence Woodman, I added an edit that will capture the outer divs only.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to switch to Nokogiri, I started switching this morning and all seems to be going well so far.